# How to solve a hyperbolic partial equation in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

How can I solve a hyperbolic partial differential equations with a numerical solution. I think is called the 5-point solution.

This is the equation I need to solve:

[image: This is the equation I need to solve]

```
h = 0.1;
k = 0.01;
a = 5;
tfinal = 0.1;
b = 2;
For[i = 0, i <= a, i++, Subscript[u, i, 0] = Sin[h*i]];
For[j = 0, j <= b, j++, Subscript[u, 0, j] = 0];
For[j = 0, j <= b, j++, Subscript[u, a, j] = 0];
c = 2;
r = c^2*k^2/h^2;
Subscript[u, 0, -1] = Subscript[u, 0, 1];
Subscript[u, -1, 0] = Subscript[u, 1, 0];

For[j = 0, j <= b, j++,
 For[i = 0, i <= a, i++,
  Subscript[u, i, j + 1] = 
   r*(Subscript[u, i - 1, j] + Subscript[u, i + 1, j]) + 
    2*(1 - r)*Subscript[u, i, j] - Subscript[u, i, j - 1]];
 Subscript[u, -i, j] = Subscript[u, i.j]; 
 Subscript[u, i, -j] = Subscript[u, i, j]]

For[i = 0, i <= a, i++,
 For[j = 0, j <= b, j++,
  Print[Subscript[u, i, j]]; Print[i, j]]]
```

Comment: You might get an answer to this over at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.  But why aren't you using `NDSolve`?

Comment: that would be the five-pint-stencil. The zero derivative solution can probably be achieved by assuming that the row at t= 0-delta has the same value as the one at t = 0 + delta

Comment: Is this a MATLAB question?  It looks like Mathematica to me.  If that's the case the 'matlab' tag should probably be removed.